# Compare integer in the list of integer array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Javascript, I have a  list of integer arrays in a single List. How can I compare the integer in the list?

```
var childOne = [];
childOne.push(3);
childOne.push(1);

var childTwo = [];
childTwo.push(4);
childTwo.push(2);

var main = [];
main.push(childOne);
main.push(childTwo);
```

How compare the integers in the child arrays?

Note: I have a json object like above mentioned "main" object. my task is, how find integers in child array are same or not?

Comment: Please, provide relevant code and explain what you have tried until now.

Comment: You have to show us some code, we will help you. Plus your question is not at all clear. Do you mean you want to find smallest integer in list? Or greatest? or see if elements are equal? Please be more precise.

Comment: Edit your question, paste your code, highlight the code and press ctrl+k.

Comment: Please, specify what should be the result of the comparison. A `List` which contains all `integer` sorted? An `array`? Many `arrays`? It make no sense with so little information. And why do you want to use `array` in `array` and do comparison on it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the main array and then compare two items. I used [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). This code returns true if all arrays in main are equal:

```
function match(arr) {
    var i, m = false;

    // checks if two arrays contain the same items    
    function intMatch(arrLeft, arrRight) {
        var l, m = arrLeft.length === arrRight.length;
        // if lenghts are different no need to check
        if (m) {
            // loop over the left array
            for(l = 0; l < arrLeft.length; l = l + 1) {
                // is it in the right array
                if (arrRight.indexOf(arrLeft[l]) === -1) {
                    m = false;
                    break; // exit for loop
                }
            }
        }
        return m;
    }

    // length-1 because we compare two items
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i = i + 1) {
        // take this item and the next one
        m = intMatch(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
        if (m === false) {
            break; // exit for loop
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Here is [the JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRR66/) in case you need to change or test stuff.